# Why doesn't firestore sync work when you close the app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Every time I enter a bank information, I need to check if the name is correct, because I want this feature to work offline, so I can not have inconsistencies in the bank. So far as the code below is working the way I want. but in only one situation does the sync fail, which is when I press the app's back button until it closes. So when I turn on the internet the data is not synchronized.

```
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('Regiao')
      .where('idRegiao', isEqualTo: idRegiao)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((data){
        data.documents.forEach((doc) {

          Firestore.instance
            .collection('CadernoCampoDefensivo')
            .document(idCadernoCampo)
            .updateData({'regiao' : doc['nomeRegiao']})
            .then((_){});


        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your app only runs when the user is actively using your app. That is working as expected, as otherwise any application could be doing whatever it wants when the app is not active, and battery life would suffer.

If this code needs to run in a single place, to respond to other users updating the data, then inside your phone is typically not the best place to do that. Instead consider running this on a server you control, or in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions). These solve the problem of both connectivity (they're much more likely to be connected to the network than a phone is), and of battery life (as they're connected to a mains power source).

Comment: I understand, but why then that in some situations firestore can synchronize data as the closed application?

In my case I want to check in a collection first, to confirm that the data is correct. But if I close the app, the data doesn't sync.

Comment: The code you shared has no reason why some of it would work and some of it would't. It usually depends more on the OS than on your code, as the OS is in control of network connections - and likely throttles more quickly if the app is not in active use.

Comment: Right.
What I want to do is very simple, I just want to update a data in the collection, and not to write inconsistent data I look for the correct name in a collection before. The problem is that the user will be offline when requesting this operation, and would like the firestore to sync automatically when connecting again. Do you know how to help me do this?